# VBA Checkbox uncheck event and multiple range load to listbox

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a small project and have difficulties with the following code. got help here with the second part of the code before (intentionally included the code for load only for the first three items (adig, altay, ataysk) to check the code:

```
        Dim adig(), altay(), altaykr(), amur(), arh(), astr(), bashk(), belgor(), bryansk(), buryat(), vladim(), volgo(), vologod(), fulllist() As Variant

        adig = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Cities").Range("adig").Value
        altay = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Cities").Range("altay").Value
        altaykr = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Cities").Range("altaykr").Value

        fulllist =ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Cities").Range("fulllist").Value

        If (Not ListofExcludelocations.Selected(0)) And Excludelocations.Value =True Then 
            For Each i In adig
                NegKeyList.AddItem i
            Next i
        End If

        If (Not ListofExcludelocations.Selected(1)) And Excludelocations.Value =true Then 
            For Each i In altay
                NegKeyList.AddItem i
            Next i
        End If

        If (Not ListofExcludelocations.Selected(3)) And Excludelocations.Value = True Then 
            For Each i In altaykr
                NegKeyList.AddItem i
            Next i          
        End If                        

        For i = NegKeyList.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1 
            If Not IsError(Application.Match(NegKeyList.List(i), fulllist, 0)) Then
                NegKeyList.RemoveItem i 
            End If
        Next i

        TextBox2.Value = NegKeyList.ListCount & " neg.keys"

    Next j          
End sub
```

the code loads items from each of the named ranges in array to the listbox1 when the checkbox is checked. This part works fine. I have difficulties with the following:
1. The second part of the code does not actually remove the items from the checkbox when it is unchecked. Could someone check what is wrong as I cannot understand it?
2. Each range (arh, astr, etc) contains different number of items. I need to make sure that if the listbox item is not selected the values from each range are loaded to listbox. The way it works now, obviously, is that I have to make separate If statement for each item. It makes the trick for little number of items, but I would like this code to be applicable for array, which has 70+ ranges in it. Can someone help me to change it in order not to need to make If statement for each item in array like it is now and rather work with For each...statement?

Comment: It would help if we would know what you are trying to do. As a user, what should happen? What is the content of the named ranges? They look a lot like single cells, too, which makes me wonder why you named them in the first place. Why not use a simply list with "cityname" and "value" being two different columns, then looping through that list to generate the content of the checkboxes?

Comment: Won't fix your code, but removing the `Else:` and `GoTo r` lines from all your `If` statements will improve readability. It's also unnecessary to have them. You may also want to give `ListBox1` and `CheckBox4` more descriptive names - future programmers, including future you, will thank you for it!

Comment: Additionally, what are all the numbered lines (1-14) for? if those are supposed to be assignment statements, there is no need for line numbers unless your version of VBA is from the early 1980s

Comment: @Freeman, I have given the names to the lists and checkbox and cleaned up the code. Sorry, I was testing so much that made it totally messy.

Comment: The ListofExcludelocations is the list of regions. Each region has different number of cities. They are located in the worksheet "Cities" (Colomn A-city names, Colomn B-respective region. @ComradeMicha, what I was trying to do is to create a ListofExcludelocations with a number of regions (named ranges). If the user checks the Excludelocations, all the items from ListofExcludelocations (except those that user selects in the ListofExcludelocations) will be added to NegKeyList. When the Excludelocations is unchecked, the user should be able to remove all the added items from the listbox.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution by copying the values to hidden listbox.

```
            For counter1 = NegKeyList.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
     For counter2 = 0 To Bcities.ListCount - 1
'InStr returns 0 when there's no match

        If (CStr(NegKeyList.List(counter1))) = (CStr(Bcities.List(counter2))) Then
            NegKeyList.RemoveItem (counter1)
            Exit For 'Skip any more compares for the deleted Item
    End If
    Next counter2
    Next counter1
```